# Getting O-bounds by applying regression methods to execution time measurements

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, experimental-analysis

Does anyone of you know how to associate an algorithm execution time (of experimental execution) to a well known complexity time? For example, say a divide and conquer algorithm lasts theoretically O(n·logn·n^2) or Ω(n·logn), in a theoretical way, doing reccurence ecuations and all that stuff. But when you plot the data from a CSV, you can't say just by looking at it 'oh yea this is O(n^2).

The data from the CSV is like:

```
n, execution_time_for_that_n...
```

How can I use a regression method to derive O-classes from such data?

Comment: I removed the parts about implementing stuff in Excel and such, since that's offtopic here.

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48505/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33854/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/857/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66378/755 for an overview of the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible. No finite set of measurements can prove asymptotic bounds.

Proof sketch: Assume you had such a method. Apply it to any algorithm $A$. If your largest measurement is for input size $n_0$, construct a new algorithm $B$ that branches into $A$ for all $n \leq n_0$, and one with a different $\Theta$-runtime class for $n > n_0$. The method fails for $B$.

That said, there *are* ways to perform reasonable experiments (for average-case performance). I recommend the book "A Guide to Experimental Algorithmics" by C. McGeoch.