# How to express time complexity when the exponential "e" comes into play?

Tags: asymptotics

I am new to all of this and I am trying to understand how to define Time Complexity. I have an algorithm which performs a set of operations on inputs of different size.

While timing the execution of such algorithm I have figured out that the time elapsed follows an exponential law:

```
Time(size)=0.15*exp(0.05*size)
```

My question: is it correct to define this complexity according to

`T(n)=O(e^n)`?

Comment: No, since for example, $\;\;\; e^{\hspace{.02 in}2\cdot n} \: = \: e^{\hspace{.02 in}n+n} \: = \: e^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}e^{\hspace{.02 in}n} \: \not\in \: O(e^{\hspace{.02 in}n}) \:\:\:\:$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Ok, and how should I describe this trend? Could it be `n*O(e^n)`?

Comment: @RickyDemer But $0.15 \mathrm{e}^{n/20}$ **is** in $O(\mathrm{e}^n)$.

Comment: Note that "time complexity" is not measured in seconds and, while you can approximate it from timing measurements, to find out what the time complexity is, you must analyse the algorithm, not use a stopwatch. "Time", in this sense, refers to computation steps, not seconds.

Comment: "I have figured out that the time elapsed follows an exponential law:" -- how? That's impossible without additional knowledge.

Comment: @Raphael I have used Python to time the script and the law I wrote is the result of the timing interpolation. I know it is not a proper measure of time complexity but all I needed was an estimate.

Comment: @FC84 See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic), [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/is-there-a-method-for-automatic-runtime-analysis-of-algorithms) and [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5004/). So no, don't even try. Do a [proper analysis](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis). On a more constructive note, how many models did you fit against your measurements, with how many parameters each? How did you decide to prefer one fit over another?

Comment: Given the answer explaining about Landau notation got accepted, I'm closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you're talking about $O$ or $\Theta$. The notation $O$ indicates that the complexity is "this much or smaller", and the notation $\Theta$ indicates that the complexity is "this much, no more or less".

The complexity of $0.15 e^{0.05 n}$ is $\Theta(e^{0.05 n})$. The complexity is not $\Theta(e^n)$, because $e^n$ grows faster than $e^{0.05 n}$ does (the ratio between the two increases without bound).

It is, in fact, true that $0.15 e^{0.05 n}$ is an $O(e^n)$ function, but this isn't a *good* description of the complexity, in much the same way that "more than a thousand people live in China" is not a good description of the population of China.

What this comes down to is that you should state the complexity as $\Theta(e^{0.05 n})$ or as $O(e^{0.05 n})$.

Comment: Also, given that the value 0.05 is only empirically measured, I would argue that it is *not* correct to claim that the complexity is $O(\mathrm{e}^{0.05n})$. It's perfectly within the realm of experimental error that the true answer is $0.14\mathrm{e}^{0.055n}$, which is still $O(\mathrm{e}^n)$ but is not $O(\mathrm{e}^{0.05n})$.  (And this is putting aside the whole issue of not being able to measure time complexity with a stopwatch.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've edited my answer; you might like the new version a little better.

Comment: Definitely better, yes. But I still take issue with statements such as "It is, in fact, true that the complexity of your algorithm is an $O(e^n)$ function", since empirical measurements can never demonstrate that. And empirical measurements certainly can't support a claim of $\Theta(\mathrm{e}^{0.05n})$.

Comment: So @DavidRicherby you have provided me and us with a number of points but what is your answer?

Comment: @CF84 My answer is that the question contains a category error, as I explained in my first comment below the question. You cannot measure time complexity with a stopwatch, so you can't deduce anything for sure about the time complexity from your measurements.