# what is the time complexity for an algorithm that operations to complete grows by 4 when doubling the input length?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I'm working on an algorithm and I'm trying to figure out its time complexity given the operations it takes to complete a input set of specific length, I have been testing the algorithm with varying input lengths.

The results shows that every time I double the input length, it takes 4 times more operations than before to complete:

- 20 items = 1M (M=million)
- 40 items = 4M
- 80 items = 16M
- 160 items = 64M
- 320 items = 256M
- 640 items = 1024M

What is the time complexity/running time that fits better with the above results?

Comment: `What is the time complexity that fits better` Better than _what_? With _n_ the number of items, the number of operations seems to be somewhere between _n_ and two to the power of _n_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recurrent equation:
$$T(n) = 4 \cdot T(\frac{n}{2})$$
$$T(1) = O(1)$$
Its solution:
$$T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$$

Comment: Hi @hekto, plotted it and matches perfectly :), thanks!

Comment: This is guesswork. A finite sample can not be used to infer asymptotic properties.

Comment: @Raphael, I simplified the question and the data provided, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Jesus Salas - Rafael means that a normal way to analyze an algorithm is to accurately count its operations. Also, algorithms can work differently on different data - so, we normally look for worst case and average case scenarios.

Comment: Just as a clarification. The way to obtain the __O(n^2)__ from the recurrence relation is by applying case 1 of the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: @HEKTO I understand what Raphael means, (sorry for my short reply to him before, I really appreciate his help), the algorithm has been tested with instances specially crafted to be hard from the processing POV of the algorithm covering the full spectrum of data distributions. The results are consistent with the above figures for any given set, (the results provided here are not the real ones). Besides I wanted to confirm my findings by asking this question, I found very hard to understand CS theory sometimes so I try to simplify my questions as much as possible to try to help others around :)

Comment: @JesusSalas You may be interested in [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33879/980).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are promised that this pattern continues ad infinitum, you can not conclude anything. Asymptotic properties can not be inferred from finite samples, ever.